# MongoDB - Update collection hourly without interrupting normal query

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, web-services, bigdata

I'm implementing a web service that needs to query a JSON file( size: ~100MB; format: [{},{},...,{}] ) about **70-80 times per second**, and the JSON file will be updated every hour. "query a JSON file" means checking if there's a JSON object in the file that has an attribute with a certain value.

Currently I think I will implement the service in Node.js, and import ( *mongoimport* ) the JSON file into a collection in MongoDB. When a request comes in, it will query the MongoDB collection instead of reading and looking up in the file directly. In the Node.js server, there should be another timer service, which in every hour checks whether the JSON file has been updated, and if it has, it needs to "repopulate" the collection with the data in the new file.

The JSON file is retrieved by sending a request to an external API. The API has two methods: methodA lets me download the entire JSON file; methodB is actually just an HTTP HEAD call, which simply tells whether the file has been updated. I cannot get the incrementally updated data from the API.

My problem is with the hourly update. With the service running, requests are coming in constantly. When the timer detects there is an update for the JSON file, it will download it and when download finishes it will try to re-import the file to the collection, which I think will take at least a few minutes. Is there a way to do this without interrupting the queries to the collection?

Above is my first idea to approach this. Is there anything wrong about the process? Looking up in the file directly just seems too expensive, especially with the requests coming in about 100 times per seconds.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the DB at all honestly given how small you say the data is (or I'd only use the DB as a backup for the "file" that is being returned).

Comment: @WiredPrairie, If I don't use DB, wouldn't reading through the file 70 - 80 times a second cause performance issues? I understand that the Node.js handels requests asynchronously, and file I/O is non-blocking, but that file contains about 20k JSON objects. I'm inexperienced dealing with such problems, could you be a little specific pls? Thanks!

Comment: I believe @user1693347 does not want the file to be sent to the client. The "downloading" he refers to must mean make the server get a fresh copy of the file. I think it is irrelevant. The point is that he wants to read the database as it is written.

Comment: Mongo (and mongoimport) will make sure that you will not read corrupt data, because each write made by mongo import will be atomic by itself. Do you mind querying data that could be a mix of old and new ? If so, import as you read and let mongo handle the locks.

Comment: Thanks @ixe013! You are right I do not need to sent the file to client. I didn't know "mongoimport" only locks the record it writes to; I don't mind querying mix data, in fact I just tried and importing  20k records finished within a second!